# Is there any license restriction to avoid binary translation of CIL to custom bytecode?

Tags: .net, licensing, virtual-machine

Prior to actual question, let me summarize what I'm trying to do. I plan to implement a small, JIT-enabled, register-based VM runtime. Instead of making a proper compiler (which is hard IMO) for a super-fancy home-brew language, I decided to implement a binary translator from a appropriate bytecode (much like Dalvik VM approach). Considering CIL vs. Java bytecode, CIL is best for my needs.

As a note, I wanted to list some important things to avoid possible confusions:

1. Base Core Library (BCL) or any Microsoft specific assemblies won't be decompiled and translated. Instead, BCL references will be subject to substitution with my VM specific codes at translation phase (much like COSMOS Plugs approach).
2. All CIL opcodes won't be translated. So, directly using CIL is not an option.
3. "Any" .NET executable is not targetted for translation. .NET will be a tool, not target.
4. Dalvik VM is good example what I'm trying to do. In Dalvik case, programs are written in Java, but Java byte codes translated into Dalvik opcodes. In my case, programs will be written in .NET, but CIL will be translated into "fancy" VM opcodes.
5. Custom VM itself will be closed source and it will be in a free software initially. But, in time, it might be used in open source and/or commercial projects.

So, is there any license restriction to avoid me doing this? If so, how can I avoid the restrictions? Making only non-profit applications or making it open source?

**EDIT:** I won't use **CLI**, **CLR** or any other thing which is distributed from Microsoft. I won't redistribute or integrate **SSCLI** into my applications either. **The question is about translating *CIL* code into custom byte codes which will be done with my own tools**. So, it's actually decompilation of my own custom .NET executables into a different byte codes to serve my needs in production phase. So, essentially I'll use .NET compilers as a front-end for my decompiler, but I won't redistribute .NET compilers either.

**EDIT2: CLI AND CIL ARE DIFFERENT THINGS!**

Comment: What does "All CLI opcodes won't be translated." mean?

Comment: You can't do that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_Source_Common_Language_Infrastructure#License

Comment: @Gabe: Translator will just give an error. You can assume endfinally as good example.

Comment: @HansPassant I understand that license disallow usage of CLI in final products. But, I'm considering to use CLI as an intermediate tool. License does not clearly cover this. Am I wrong?

Comment: Interpreting licenses to your liking is what keeps lawyers and court rooms busy.  This is not the right place to ask for legal advice.

Comment: A good runtime is hard too.  Why do you need it?

Comment: @Hans: I don't understand the relevance of your Wikipedia link. OP wants to translate CIL, not redistribute SSCLI.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Yeah. It's really challenging. But, do you know a better way to compress files at Kolmogorov complexity? I want to keep runtime minumum. So, I'm obviously not planning to implement CLR or JVM equivalent.

Comment: @OsmanTuran I have no idea what Kolmogorov complexity is or do - but perhaps others do.  Perhaps open a question about it?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Please look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity . It simply means for a given input data, minumum compressed size defined by minumum program size that can generate the input back. Consider compressing of one million PI digits with a universal compressor (like ZIP), or generate it from a small console application. Guess which one is smaller? :) VM for compression is not a new idea BTW. RAR has a x86 like VM for years.

Comment: @OsmanTuran so it is a question of generating a program for producing the desired bit sequence?  Why not just target the CLR or the JVM then?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: "producing the desired bit sequence" is kinda inaccurate but, more or less same. CLR, especially Java is not suited for my goals e.g. Java doesn't support unsigned int which is frequently used in my compression models. With translation, some substitution will be applied based on inherited interfaces. So, actually CLR won't be narrowed, it'll be expanded. Offline translation also has another benefit, because it can take up to several hours and can produce really small and fast byte codes by profiling several possibilities on real data.

Comment: @OsmanTuran sounds like you've thought this through.  Good luck.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Thanks for your invaluable comments :)

Comment: @Osman Turan, have you considered implementing Forth (as a form of a generic and extensible compact stack-based VM)? And yes, it is perfectly ok to translate *your*  own code from CLR to whatever else. As long as you're not touching `mscorlib` and alike it cannot be restricted at all. Use the Mono toolchain as a frontend just in case.

Comment: Forth can be considered as high-level IR. So, in that case it's unsuitable for me. Because, most of optimization job will be implemented in my translator. So, final JIT won't do too much job and this will reduce JIT code size. As to Mono toolchain, I can even write my own C# to CIL compiler, if I "really" need it (actually I don't want to implement it due to lack of time). The problem is CIL's intellectual properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i had understood your question correctly i think all you are saying is that you will create your own system (compiler or Virtual machine) which takes *CIL byte codes* and *do something interesting*. This *do something* can be of course translating into executable or another IL which is later interpreted.

Now the question really is - the CIL being a Microsoft intellectual property will they sue you?

The [wiki link of Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28programming%29) provides some interesting links on this; Accordingly,

> When Microsoft first announced their .NET Framework in June 2000 it
>   was described as "a new platform based on Internet standards", and
>   in December of that year the underlying Common Language Infrastructure
>   was published as an open standard, ["ECMA-335"](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-WITHDRAWN/ECMA-335,%201st%20edition,%20December%202001.pdf) - opening up the
>   potential for independent implementations.

[Here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) is the home for this reference. The [Microsoft's development center's page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569283.aspx) gives good details. According to this *CIL instruction set* is part (part III) of the specs in overall CLI standard. The site also mentions that there are following companies involved in developing this standard.

> Many of the organizations that have participated in the TC39/TG2 and
>   TC39/TG3 work have volunteered to mirror this site. The links for the
>   mirror sites are:
>
> Intel Corporation,
>   ISE (Eiffel),
>   IT University, Copenhagen
>   Kahu Research, New Zealand
>   Microsoft Corporation
>   Novell (Mono)

According to same [wiki reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28programming%29):

> On July 6, 2009, Microsoft announced that it was placing their ECMA
>   334 and ECMA 335 specifications under their Community Promise pledging
>   that they would not assert their patents against anyone implementing,
>   distributing, or using alternative implementations of .NET

Now based on all above research, we can say that - given that the ECMA is an open standard, you can actually do *legally* what you propose to do.

NOTE: there are some component not included in this spec. Also, using .NET CLR itself is not part this discussion.

DISCLAIMER: But yes, great many details go in legality. So since i am not lawyer, my advise to you is for free but without any warranty! :)

Comment: I've read both your answer and it's links several times. Most interesting part was that ECMA 334 (especially Partition III: CIL Instruction Set) is under Microsoft's Community Promise allows anyone to freely implement alternative implementation of .NET. This answers my question precisely. I was afraid of Microsoft would eventually sue me due to using (actually translating) CIL which is Microsoft's intellectual property. Most of my concern's root was Dalvik VM due to it's same thing what I'm trying to do. But, I've read some sources Oracle sued Google for using it's intellectual properties.